# Memory Corruption in c

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, g++

I am using c in linux, when i run main.c i get below error:

> *** glibc detected**  /asde/pasc/source/cl/weasdashanges/webasdnges: malloc():
>   memory corruption: 0x08069098 **

the backtrace from gdb is as follows: its pointing to function dblogin which is strange because i am pretty sure that should not be the problem because i never made changes there.

```
if ((login = dblogin()) == FAIL)        return 0;
```

and this code was working fine before the changes.

```
 (gdb) backtrace
    #0  0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
    #1  0x002f7651 in raise () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
    #2  0x002faa82 in abort () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
    #3  0x0032e49d in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
    #4  0x00338591 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
     #5  0x0033b395 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
     #6  0x0033c70b in calloc () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
     #7  0x001f9cd6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5
     #8  0x001edd1a in dblogin () from /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5
     #9  0x0804de13 in ?? ()
    #10 0x0804e01b in ?? ()
     #11 0x0804bf9f in ?? ()
    #12 0x002e3bd6 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
    #13 0x0804a031 in ?? ()
```

Any ideas on how i can find out whats the specific problem? like a gdb command tells it to break on every write to that location

Comment: @kerek SB i know that but thats not my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find out memory leaks in your program. Also use more your debugger.

If you want to find out how is a particular location overwritten, you could use the *watch* command of `gdb`

Comment: +1 for valgrind. It will (almost certainly) find his problem immediately.